# Match the last parenthesis group

Tags: regex

I have a string that looks like this

*Some text (group1) some more text (group2) some more text (groupN)*

Can somebody help me to write a regular expression that matches groupN? That group is always at the end of the text.

I tried this expression

```
\(.+\)
```

But, it matches from the opening parenthesis of group1 to the closing parenthesis of groupN. I only need to match groupN.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following regular expression. It matches only at the end of the input string. (`$` matches the end of the input string or end of line according to regular expression engines.)

```
\([^()]+\)$
```

Javascript example:

```
> 'Some text (group1) some more text (group2) some more text (groupN)'.match(/\([^()]+\)$/)
["(groupN)"]
```

Answer (score 2):

If the final parenthesis might have text appearing after it, as in:

```
some text (first) and (last) more text
```

You can use a lookahead to check there are no more parenthesis in the string after the match:

```
\([^)]*\)(?=[^(]*$)
```

If not then just match a `$` as falsetru correctly suggests.

[RegExr](http://regexr.com?37gdd)